# Animate label with bar chart - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

The code below animates a bar chart and associated label values. The issue I'm having is positioning the label when the integer is negative. Specifically, I want the label to be positioned on top of the bar, not inside it. It's working for the first frame but the subsequent frames of animation revert back to plotting the label inside the bar chart for negative integers.

```
def autolabel(rects, ax):

    # Get y-axis height to calculate label position from.
    ts = []

    (y_bottom, y_top) = ax.get_ylim()
    y_height = y_top - y_bottom

    for rect in rects:

        height = 0
        if rect.get_y() < 0:
            height = rect.get_y()
        else:
            height = rect.get_height()

        p_height = (height / y_height)

        if p_height > 0.95: 
            label_position = height - (y_height * 0.05) if (height > -0.01) else height + (y_height * 0.05) 
        else:
            label_position = height + (y_height * 0.01) if (height > -0.01) else height - (y_height * 0.05) 

        t = ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., label_position,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
    
        ts.append(t)
    
    return ts

def gradientbars(bars, ax, cmap, vmin, vmax):

    g = np.linspace(vmin,vmax,100)
    grad = np.vstack([g,g]).T
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    ims = []

    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_facecolor('none')
        im = ax.imshow(grad, aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))
        im.set_clip_path(bar)
        ims.append(im)
    
    return ims

vmin = -6
vmax = 6
cmap = 'PRGn'

data = np.random.randint(-5,5, size=(10, 4))

x = [chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(4)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_ylim(vmin, vmax)
rects = ax.bar(x,data[0])

labels = autolabel(rects, ax)
imgs = gradientbars(rects, ax, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

def animate(i):
    for rect,label,img,yi in zip(rects, labels, imgs, data[i]):
        rect.set_height(yi)
        label.set_text('%d'%int(yi))
        label.set_y(yi)
        img.set_clip_path(rect)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(data), interval = 500)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's working for the first frame.

You call `autolabel(rects, ax)` in the first plot, so the label is well placed.

> The subsequent frames of animation revert back to plotting the label inside the bar chart for negative integers.

The label position of subsequent frames is set by `label.set_y(yi)`. `yi` is from `data[i]`, you didn't consider the negative value here.

I create a function named `get_label_position(height)` to calculate the right label position for give height. It uses a global variable `y_height`. And call this function before `label.set_y()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def get_label_position(height):
    p_height = (height / y_height)

    label_position = 0
    if p_height > 0.95: 
        label_position = height - (y_height * 0.05) if (height > -0.01) else height + (y_height * 0.05)
    else:
        label_position = height + (y_height * 0.01) if (height > -0.01) else height - (y_height * 0.05)

    return label_position


def autolabel(rects, ax):

    # Get y-axis height to calculate label position from.
    ts = []

    (y_bottom, y_top) = ax.get_ylim()
    y_height = y_top - y_bottom

    for rect in rects:

        height = 0
        if rect.get_y() < 0:
            height = rect.get_y()
        else:
            height = rect.get_height()

        p_height = (height / y_height)

        if p_height > 0.95: 
            label_position = height - (y_height * 0.05) if (height > -0.01) else height + (y_height * 0.05) 
        else:
            label_position = height + (y_height * 0.01) if (height > -0.01) else height - (y_height * 0.05) 

        t = ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2., label_position,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
    
        ts.append(t)
    
    return ts

def gradientbars(bars, ax, cmap, vmin, vmax):
    g = np.linspace(vmin,vmax,100)
    grad = np.vstack([g,g]).T
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    ims = []

    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_facecolor('none')
        im = ax.imshow(grad, aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))
        im.set_clip_path(bar)
        ims.append(im)
    
    return ims

vmin = -6
vmax = 6
cmap = 'PRGn'

data = np.random.randint(-5,5, size=(10, 4))

x = [chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(4)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_ylim(vmin, vmax)
rects = ax.bar(x,data[0])

labels = autolabel(rects, ax)
imgs = gradientbars(rects, ax, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

(y_bottom, y_top) = ax.get_ylim()
y_height = y_top - y_bottom

def animate(i):
    for rect,label,img,yi in zip(rects, labels, imgs, data[i]):
        rect.set_height(yi)
        label.set_text('%d'%int(yi))
        label.set_y(get_label_position(yi))
        img.set_clip_path(rect)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(data), interval = 500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The first frame appears to be working, which is confusing. If I comment out the animation function it produces the attached figure (which is ideal). However, subsequent frames revert back to plotting label inside bar for negative ints.

Comment: @jonboy Sorry for not well considered your problem, I have edited my answer.